# Galería Inteligente [COMPLEJO]

Tags: php, ajax, gd

Buenas, estoy creando un sistema que tiene una galería inteligente, es una web para crear y personalizar cuadros, el cliente selecciona el marco, y la imagen debe crearse dentro de un cuadro e ir personalizándola con diferentes molduras, esto yo logre hacerlo, y esta trabajando el tema es que lo hice probando con un solo marco, pues todos los marcos tienen la misma medida, y están alojados en una base de datos, lo único que haría es cambiar el nombre y listo pues debería ser igual para todas, EL **ERROR** que tengo es que cuando selecciono otro marco que debería de funcionar igual que el primero este pierde su color totalmente, es decir se ve la imagen pero se queda como descolorada, pierde su color. Acá les mando , el codigo

```js
private function createPhoto($src, $imageType,$width,$height,$frame_picture){ //Enviamos los parametros desde el cliente al servidor           
                $url = str_replace("../lienzoarte_backend/img/", "/", $_POST['image_name']);//Transformo la URL mas dinamica
                $data = "../../lienzoarte_backend/img/$url";
                $this->image = $this->openImage($data); //ABRIMOS LA IMAGEN PRINCIPAL
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image); //ANCHO
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image); //ALTO
                $this->resizeImage($width,$height,$this->getImageForm($imageType));//Funcion que ajusta la imagen, y le pasa por parametro una funcion que devuelve que tipo de imagen es, LEER QUE HACE LA FUNCION ABAJO
                $path = str_replace(".jpg", "-modified.jpg", $data); //GUARDA LA IMAGEN MODIFICADA PARA NO SOBRESCRIBIR LA ORIGINAL                 
                /*
                 * FRAME 
                 */
                $frame_url = "../../lienzoarte_backend/img/{$frame_picture}";//MISMO PASO PERO CON EL MARCO
                $frame = imagecreatefrompng($frame_url);//CREAMOS EL MARCO
                imagecopyresampled($frame, $this->image, 140, 145,0,0, $width,$height, $this->width, $this->height); // INSERTAMOS LA IMAGEN DENTRO DEL MARCO, EL 140 Y 145 ES LA POSICION PARA QUE SE VEA DENTRO DEL MARCO
                imagejpeg($frame, $path,100); // GUARDAMOS LA IMAGEN
                $object = array(); // DEVOLVEMOS UN JSON AL CLIENTE PARA CAMBIAR LA IMAGEN DINAMICAMENTE 
                $object["data"] = $this->generateRandomString(7);
                $object["imageType"] = $imageType;              
                $object["test"] = $this->getImageForm($imageType);
                $object["width"] = $this->sizeWidthFixed($imageType);
                $object["height"] = $this->sizeHeightFixed($imageType);
                $object["width_2"] = $this->width;
                $object["frame"]  = $frame_picture;
                $object["height_2"] = $this->height;
                echo json_encode($object);
            
                    imagedestroy($this->image);
                    imagedestroy($frame);
                
           
    }
```

Aqui es la función que ajusta la imagen por si aqui genera el error

```js
  public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
    {
    $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, strtolower($option)); //ES LA FUNCION QUE AJUSTA LA IMAGEN SEGUN SU DIMENSIONES  
    $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
   $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
   imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);
   $option = 'crop';
// 
// 
    // *** ESTO ES PARA RECORTAR LOS ESPACIOS DE SOBRA DE LA IMAGEN
    if ($option == 'crop') {
        $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }
    /******************************************************
     * crop
     */
    
    }
```

```js
   private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option='crop')
    {
        
        switch($option)
        {
            case 'exact':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;            
            break;
            case 'portrait':
                $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
            case 'landscape':
            $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
            case 'auto':
            $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
            case 'crop':
            $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
            
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }
```

Esto lo envio desde el cliente, les adjunto un ejemplo, EL MISMO CODIGO para todo, la primera moldura sale perfecta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora cuando cambio de moldura simplemente se descolora
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo _encarecidamente_ el uso de una librería como [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) y no reinventar la rueda con el tema del re-dimensionado y recortado de imágenes.